# How set background for ActionBar

Tags: android

How me set background for ActionBar program method? Extends AppCombatActivity. Method .set them() d'n work. How me it make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorResID)));
```

This is for setting background color for `AppCompatActivity`

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
sha